# Class 'App\Eloquent' not found in laravel after running php artisan db:seed

Tags: php, laravel

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface 
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your model should extend the `Model` class:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class User extends Model
```

If you want to use Laravel authentication system, it should extend `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class User extends Authenticatable
```